# Quarto dataframe printing and styling

Tags: r, kable, quarto

In quarto, we have the option to control the default [printing of dataframes](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/r.html#data-frames), e.g.

````
---
title: "Example"
format:
  html:
    df-print: kable
---

## example kable

```{r}
mtcars |> head()
dim(mtcars)
```
````

[image: example kable]

Now I would like to make some `kable_styling` to make it more appealing. I found an option that works,

````
---
title: "Example"
format:
  html
---

```{r}
#| include: false
knit_print.data.frame = function(x, ...) {
  res = paste(c("", "", 
                knitr::kable(x, digits = 2) |> 
                  kableExtra::kable_styling()), collapse = "\n")
  knitr::asis_output(res)
}

registerS3method(
  "knit_print", "data.frame", knit_print.data.frame,
  envir = asNamespace("knitr")
)
```

## example kable


```{r}
mtcars |> head()
dim(mtcars)
```
````

[image]

My problem is that it works on a stand-alone HTML file, but when I have several `.qmd`'s for a book, it does not work. Hence, I look for a solution that adds the styling inside the YAML or to make the above mentioned solution work for all qmd-files in a Quarto book.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution could be creating an R-script file (suppose `global.R`) in the Book project root directory containing,

**global.R**

```
knit_print.data.frame = function(x, ...) {
  res = paste(c("", "", 
                knitr::kable(x, digits = 2) |> 
                  kableExtra::kable_styling()), collapse = "\n")
  knitr::asis_output(res)
}

registerS3method(
  "knit_print", "data.frame", knit_print.data.frame,
  envir = asNamespace("knitr")
)
```

and source this script at the beginning of each `.qmd` file,

````
```{r include=FALSE}
source("global.R")
```
````

Comment: Yes, this is also my less clean implementation at the moment. I hoped for a more general, less code intensive solution though, but maybe it is not yet possible..

Comment: Well, so far, In quarto Book project, quarto runs each qmd file in separate environment and AFAIK, theres no way to have a global R script that will apply for all qmd files in project directory.

Comment: Okay then it would only work if there exists a YAML solution. Nevertheless, thank you for your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

My current solution uses `df-print: kable` and some additional css styling of the row stripes, e.g.

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd)>* {

    --bs-table-accent-bg: rgb(81 191 237 / 5%);
    color: var(--bs-table-striped-color);
}
```